# How to debug firefox performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox

I have a web application which loads fast in Chrome, but in FireFox it appears to spend 10-20 seconds frozen to input.

During this time there is nothing showing as loading in the network tab, and having profiled using the performance tab there isn't any meaningful output. During this time it reports different scripts running, but nothing that would take the 30 seconds it is reporting. FF reports that I get 0fps but doesn't otherwise report FF doing anything.

Is there any more I can do to try to work out what firefox is doing during this time?

Comment: Do you have scripts running? If disabling all those scripts helps, try enabling them one-by-one, and see which causes problems ... Depending on how (dis)organised your scripts are, this may or may not be a lot of work, though.

Comment: I do have quite a few scripts, although the profiler isn't showing any particular script running when it freezes (different profiler runs have different "long" executing parts). I suspect it may be a localstorage thing, as we use a lot of it (3M+).

Comment: That's entirely possible, but something only you can test :-) If disabling isn't an option (ie. your entire app would stop working), you could do some strategic `console.log()` calls to determine if that's the problem, and get an indication where the app hangs.